# How do I find the Column ID for a Grid Entry Field in Expression Engine Channel Forms

Tags: ee2, channel-form

I am looking to add a grid entry to Channel Form. I can see the field in the Field Groups list, but i cannot locate the Column id for the actual entry.

```
<input type="hidden" name="field_id_59[rows][new_row_0][]" value="new_row_0" />
<input type="text" name="field_id_59[rows][new_row_0][col_id_**????**]" value=""/>
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to see at a glance is to just throw the whole field onto the page and then view the source. So include this in your templates:

```
{field:field_name}
```

Where `field_name` is the name of your grid field.

Then you'll be able to identify the column IDs. The code you require will end up looking something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="field_id_1[rows][new_row_0][]" value="new_row_0" />
<input type="text" name="field_id_1[rows][new_row_0][col_id_1]" value="" />
```

`field_id_1` relates to the field ID of the grid field itself and `col_id_1` will be the column ID in that grid field that you're targeting.

Comment: That was useful thanks, I also figured out I could look directly into the DB using Tools --> Data --> SQL Manager.